# Unable to input text into input fields in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SignUp = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const register = () => {
    const { name, email, password } = user;
    if (name && email && password) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signup", user)
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    } else {
      alert("Invalid input");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Sign up</h1>
      <br />

      <span className="input"></span>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="name"
        value={user.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Full name"
        required
      />
      <span className="input"></span>
      <input
        type="email"
        className="email"
        placeholder="Email address"
        required
        value={user.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <span id="passwordMeter"></span>
      <input
        type="password"
        className="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={user.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <button type="submit" onClick={register}>
        <span>Sign up</span>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

I have already set up the backend server, running on localhost port 8800. It includes the user schema and POST method for user registration. However, the issue I'm currently facing is that I am unable to input any text within the input fields. The goal is to capture the user's information and eventually store it in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input element's `value`s are controlled by your `user` state, so if you don't update your state correctly then you won't be able to type inside your inputs. Your problem is that you're trying to grab the `name` attribute from your input element to determine which property in your state to update, however, your input elements don't have a `name` attribute so your state can't update correctly and thus allow your inputs to work correctly.

To fix this, set a `name` attribute on each of your inputs to the same value as name of the property you're reading in the `value` attribute:

```js
<input
  type="text"
  name="name" // "name" because that's the key we want to update in `user` so that `user.name` in the `value` will be set correctly. 
  className="name"
  value={user.name}
  onChange={handleChange}
  placeholder="Full name"
  required
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SignUp = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const register = () => {
    const { name, email, password } = user;
    if (name && email && password) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signup", user)
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    } else {
      alert("Invalid input");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Sign up</h1>
      <br />

      <span className="input"></span>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="name"
        name="name"
        value={user.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Full name"
        required
      />
      <span className="input"></span>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        className="email"
        placeholder="Email address"
        required
        value={user.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <span id="passwordMeter"></span>
      <input
        type="password"
        className="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={user.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <button type="submit" onClick={register}>
        <span>Sign up</span>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

You have to simply add a `name` attribute, because you are targeting the element but it is not finding which element you are targeting.

so the name attribute will help.